# Android Listview blur effect for items

Tags: java, android, blur

I have problem blur listview item. I found the solution for normal image bluring but it does not works for listview.

[image: ListView Items]

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work for ListView? Which method do you call and how is your layout build?

Comment: blur action calls before loading backgroud image and I need a very fast solution so that the items can scroll fast.

Answer (score -1):

I did it something different that you need, hope to be helpful!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nombre_coche"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/background_footer"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"  //IMPORTANT FOR YOU
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</FrameLayout>
```

[image: shows that]

Spanish info provided from: http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/07/tutorial-para-crear-un-gridview-en-android/

**UPDATED**

I think that adding `android:alpha="0.5"` on `TextView` should do what you're looking for!

Comment: OP asked about blur, not alpha.